# Busco una herramienta geo para crear un mapa de calor de un país en especifico

Tags: javascript

Probé con google maps, pero me gustaria mostrar solo la composicion politica de ese pais y no del resto

Comment: Este es un sitio en español. Si no editas tu pregunta, puede ser que sea puesta en espera o que sea cerrada. Tambien te recomiendo ver el siguiente enlace para mejorar tu pregunta https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: estas en stackoverflow en español tu pregunta debe ser en español , ademas este sitios es para aclarar dudas no para debatir, si quieres debatir te recomiendo entrar al chat cuando tenga los puntos suficientes

Comment: Disculpas, no me di cuenta que entre en el sitio en español. Y no lo publiqué a modo de debate.

Comment: Esta bien. Me parece que la pregunta tiene el potencial de ser buena, ya que es un buen tema. Solo hace falta traducirla y editarla para evidenciar tu problema real y de seguro obtendras una buena respuesta y ayudaras a otras personas que esten buscando cosas parecidas. Saludos.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Trata usando **Highcharts**, específicamente **HighMaps**. Es gratis, aquí dejo [el enlace](https://www.highcharts.com/maps/demo).